# Framer-Motion, toggle between 2 different enter and Exit states

Tags: reactjs, animation, state, framer-motion

I'm trying to animate some elements based on weather the user is progressing forward or backward.  e.g. `state > prevState` or `state < prevState`

Here is what the logic looks like.

-Hook to update state and track previous state

```
import { useState } from "react";
export default function useStateWithPrevious(initial) {
    const [value, setValue] = useState(initial);
    const [prev, setPrev] = useState(initial);

    function setValueAndPrev(newValue) {
        if (newValue === value) return; // optional, depends on the logic you want.
        setPrev(value);
        setValue(newValue);
    }

    return [prev, value, setValueAndPrev];
}
```

Hook use

```
const [previousRegistrationDay, registrationDay, setRegistrationDay] = useSetDayWithPreviousDay(1);
```

Here is the Framer Motion Component.

```
<AnimatePresence mode="wait">
    <motion.nav
        key={registrationDay}
        animate={{ x: "0%", opacity: 1 }}
        transition={{ duration: 0.5 }}
        initial={{ opacity: 0, x: previousRegistrationDay < registrationDay ? "100%" : "-100%" }}
        exit={{ opacity: 0, x: previousRegistrationDay < registrationDay ? "-100%" : "100%" }}
    >
        <div>
            registrationDay{registrationDay}
            <br />
            previousRegistrationDay{previousRegistrationDay}
        </div>
    </motion.nav>
</AnimatePresence>
```

Example
https://youtu.be/lmob3oJUgkA

This works for the most part, but the first time you "go back" / "change directions" the animation exit is wrong.

It's like there is a closure around the variables defining the exit transition, causing it to be wrong the first time the `prevState > state` and then switching to `prevState < state`

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is [variants](https://www.framer.com/motion/animation/#variants) with [custom argument](https://www.framer.com/motion/animation/##dynamic-variants) and [custom prop](https://www.framer.com/motion/animate-presence/###custom) of AnimatePresence.

You define your animations as variant which accepts custom argument (direction in your case) and depending on it returns desired properties. Then you need to pass direction as `custom` prop to both your component (to make appear animation work correctly) and to AnimatePresence to make exit animation aware of direction too.

Here is example how it's implemented in my project:

1. [Calculate direction](https://github.com/OlegWock/anori/blob/master/src/plugins/calendar/calendar-plugin.tsx#L55)
2. [Define variants](https://github.com/OlegWock/anori/blob/master/src/plugins/calendar/calendar-plugin.tsx#L62-L83)
3. Pass variants and custom [to component](https://github.com/OlegWock/anori/blob/master/src/plugins/calendar/calendar-plugin.tsx#L105-L110) and to [AnimatePresence](https://github.com/OlegWock/anori/blob/master/src/plugins/calendar/calendar-plugin.tsx#L144)

**UPD:** I wrote an [article](https://sinja.io/blog/direction-aware-animations-in-framer-motion) about this with examples in my blog.